# MS Excel : point a cell by concatenating text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

In Microsoft Excel 2013, I want to point to a cell with this kind of formula :

```
=Sheet1!["A"+E1]
```

Where `E1` contains the number of the line, for instance `25`.

So the purpose of the formula is to get to the cell `A25` of Sheet 1.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer, I must use the `INDIRECT()` function :

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & E1; TRUE)
```

Still with `E1` containing the line number.